# Is it a problem that my contractor drilled vertically through a beam?

Tags: drill, structural, beam

I hired a contractor to run some low voltage ethernet wires through my house, but I can't shake a gut feeling that he may have done something that he shouldn't have.

Running a cable to the back of the house and to the roof of my sunroom, he attempted to drill vertically through a sistered 2x10 header with a double top plate on it, that the roof joists of the sun room are sitting on top of.

He gave up after 4 attempts and just went out the sheathing right under the beam instead, which he probably should have done from the start, but that is besides the point.

I did contact the contractor that did the work, and said that it shouldn't be a problem but did shove a tie plate on there to make me feel better.

This probably is a load bearing beam, correct? Is this a major concern? I've already attempted to contact several structural engineers but they are few and far between in my area.

Below is a drawing of the framing in question to the best of what I was able to see in the wall.

[image: Wall Drawing]

Wall interior, patch is where holes were drilled.

*edit more clear picture of how this is framed from the inside.

[image: Wall interior]

Sunroom in general

[image]

Comment: The diameter and location of the holes is important to know.  With the two supports on each side, it should be low concern, done over the door would be more concerning if they were larger than 1/2 inch holes.

Comment: If that beam has two studs under it as in your diagram it's certainly not an issue.

Comment: The holes look to be 3/4" each, so stacked next to each other they probably a little smaller than 1.5" x 3/4"

The are located 19" from the end of the left wall and the wall itself is 11' 4". 

Sorry I'm not exact on everything, I quickly patched the wall up so the 100 degree heat could stop leaking into my house.

Comment: How else should have that be done ?

Comment: When you get time just repaint that wall/patch.  Keeping a note saying where the holes where made, in case those supports need to replaced in the future won't hurt(probably be forgotten by then).

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine. The contractor probably didn't get very far without a proper hammer drill with a long enough bit. A 3/4 inch drill bit all the way up to the attic is pretty standard. You have quite a few verticle 2x4s holding that beam in place.

My understanding of load bearing is that this is not load bearing. It is just an exterior wall beam.

Comment: They wouldn't need a hammer drill for drilling through timber, would they?

Comment: With the roof trusses sitting on top of that wall perpendicular to it, would that beam carry the load of the roof down to the vertical framing members?

Comment: @Petefish, Yes. That is a load bearing wall. The wall &beam must carry the weight of the roof. However, given the location of the holes, it should be fine.

Comment: @carl we used a large rotary hammer drill with a long auger type wood bit on it.

Comment: Load bearing for that section of roof, I suppose. I was looking for a larger space above it, like an attic

Comment: @andrew hammer drill but without hammer action enabled, right? Given that an auger bit is meant to pull itself into the wood via a screw mechanism I would imagine that hammering would be counterproductive and blunt the bit.